# Drop a database being accessed by another users?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to drop a database from PgAdmin 3 and I get this error message:

```
ERROR: can't delete current database
SQL state: 55006
```

how can I force the delete/fix this error, of this database?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quick fix in PgAdmin: just create another empty database.  Select it.  Delete the first one. Voila.

You can also connect to the command line without selecting a specific database, and drop your database.

The problem here is not that **other users** are connected to the database, but that **you** are.

Comment: "You can also connect to the command line without selecting a specific database, ..." - not true. Probably you're misled because when you start psql and do not specify a DB name psql tries to connect to a DB named after the user you have specified (or the system user if that's missing too).

Comment: In pgAdmin 4, I just had to left click on the postgres DB itself, then right click on my target DB and delete it.

Answer (score 19):

[This post](http://www.leeladharan.com/drop-a-postgresql-database-if-there-are-active-connections-to-it) by Leeladharan Achar was helpful for me in working with this error.

It essentially boils down to:

```sql
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'target_db'
  AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();

DROP DATABASE target_db;
```

Comment: I had to remove the quotes from the last line, so it read `DROP DATABASE target_db;`. I kept them in the third line though

Answer (score 8):

Simplest fix for this is **restart the postgresql**. After that You can get rid of database!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the pgAdmin4 interface, you have to first delete/drop the db, then, before waiting for the error, you have to immediatelly disconnect from the same database, then it gets deleted without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating new database he can simply connect to postgres database, which is created by default in all new PostgreSQL installations. And even if it is not there - template1 should be always there.

Answer (score 0):

**The best method to drop user is below mentioned**

Like i have a user name is "X" and it have access permission to database name : "Test" .
And now we are created connection with "Test" database

If we try: drop user "X" this will be definality show below mentioned error:

**ERROR: user "X" cannot be dropped because the user has a privilege on some object SQL State=55006**

First of all connection should not be created with "Test" db.because it currently use so we are not able to delete the user.
create connection with any of database except eg "Test"
Now again try 
drop user test
It should be worked fine on my side,let me know if you are facing issue on your side

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and perhaps the neatest fix is to go to services and stop the PostgreSQL server and then start it, and then run the `drop database yourdbname;` command again. That should disconnect any sessions and allow you to drop the current database.