# How to manage the migration SQLserver to PostgreSQL with Npgsql?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I’m doing a web application with MVC pattern in C# for an internship.

I’m trying to migrate my SQLserver database created by EntityFramework to a PostgreSQL database.

I found a solution on internet: Npgsql. It seems to do the job, now I need to implement this solution…

I found two explanations to install Npgsql:

1) Code Project: [Using PostgreSQL with Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783552/Using-PostgreSQL-with-Entity-Framework-in-ASP-NET)

2) Npgsql.org: [Npgsql Getting Started doc](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html)

The first one doesn’t allow to use CodeFirst, I’m not sure if this is very important because I already have my database scheme on SQLserver. I’m worrying about some class who have another class for property, I’m not sure that a database without codefirst will implement that.

The second solution, if I understand well, allows CodeFirst but I have 4 issues :

1. This solution is for console app, I don’t know if it will work
   with a web app?
2. There is something I don't understand, I was working with the
   assembly System.Data.Entity, why does this solution use
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore? What are the differences between
   those assemblies?
3. Let's suppose I can apply this solution to my web app, I don’t
   understand the namespace used by the solution to define the DB (the
   class inherits of DbContext): `nameOfTheSolution.PostgreSQL`? Is it
   important? I wasn’t sure, so I kept the namespace
   `nameOfTheSolution.Models`.
4. The website says that I must add a few lines of code to the file
   “startup.cs”, if I’m not wrong, this file doesn’t exist in my
   solution. So I tried to add this few lines inside "global.asax.cs", is
   it correct?

With all the choices I made, I try to build my app but I get an error:

> “Npgsql.PostgresException : '42P01: the relation « Solution » doesn't exist'”

I don’t understand this because this table is supposed to be created.

How can I adapt the second solution proposed by Npgsql's website into my web application?

---

**EDIT :**

As Shay Rojansky advised me, I tried to use Npgsql with EF 6 so with EntityFramework6.Npgsql.

At the beginning, I tried to do that on my real project but after several fails, I tried on a Console app I create for the occasion.

This is the program, the model, the creation of my DBcontext and the connection string :

```
//program.cs
using System;
using System.Linq;


namespace PostgreCodeFirst
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CarContext context = new CarContext();

            Car cars = new Car();
            cars.LicenceNumber = 2;
            cars.Insurance = "cool";
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="Host=localhost;port=5432;database=carsDB;User ID=user;password=password" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.8.0" newVersion="4.0.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace PostgreCodeFirst
{
    public class CarContext : DbContext
    {
        public CarContext() : base("Default")
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace PostgreCodeFirst
{
    public class Car
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public int LicenceNumber { get; set; }
        public string Insurance { get; set; }

    }
}
```

At the beginning the issue was that the CodeFirst migration didn't work. There is no errors about the connection but no table was created by the program. So I search and find this solution :

[Errors with tables creation by code first model with npgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524540/errors-with-tables-creation-by-code-first-model-with-npgsql)

Now I have another issue and I can't find any solution : My context creates the tables but doesn't want to save the data; the “Context.SaveChanges()”

Do you have any idea why I can’t save my data ?

Comment: You need to read and understand about "classical" Entity Framework 6 and the newer Entity Framework Core, and decide exactly what you want to do. Do you have an EF6 SQL Server project using code first? Do you want to migrate to EF6 PostgreSQL or EF Core PostgreSQL?

Comment: You are right, i didn’t know there was a difference between EF6 and EF Core.
If I understand correctly, I already use EF6 with a local SQLserver. I would like to migrate to PostgreSQL.
Since the beggining of my internship, I don’t have any informations about the servers, the only thing I know is that there is a server for the database and another one for the application. 
I think I will get a Windows server so any solution could work. I am just searching for the easier to deploy.

Comment: OK. If you plan to port to EF6 you will need to use the package EntityFramework6.Npgsql. Note that this is much less well-maintained and feature-rich than the EF Core PostgreSQL provider, but it should work for normal scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I edited my question with some new issues ^^'